# Bounded sequence of real numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $<a_n>$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers, where $n = 1,2,3,4,...$. Then which of the following are true?

1. Every subsequence of $<a_n>$ is convergent.
2. There is exactly one subsequence of $<a_n>$ which is convergent.
3. There are infinite subsequences of $<a_n>$ which are convergent.
4. There is a subsequence of $<a_n>$ which is convergent.

My Attempt:
Let $< 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2...>$ be a bounded sequence and every subsequence of this sequence is convergent. So $2$,$3$ can be discarded.

Comment: " Let <0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2...> be a bounded sequence and every subsequence of this sequence is convergent."  Why do you say that?  It, itself isn't convergent.  Neither is $0,1,0,1,0,1.....$.  Or $0,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,1,....$ very few are convergent.

Comment: Take the sequence $(-1)^n$. It is bounded, and every subsequence of this sequence is bounded, but it does not convergene. Similarly, we can find subsequences that do not converge.

Comment: Also in this context "there is one" means "there is at least one" as opposed to "exactly one".  If $1$ is true then $4$ is true but $2$ and $3$ are false.  If $2$ is true then $4$ is true but $1$ and $3$ are false. If $3$ is true then $4$ is true and $2$ is false and $1$ may or may not be true.  If $4$ is true then all the others may or may not be true.

Comment: Also, I hope you are aware when the say $n= 1,2,3,4....$ then mean the *indexes* of $a_n$.  the $a_i$ values can still be anything.

Comment: Ohh, I made a mistake in my attempt. Thanks for point out the mistake.

Comment: Is only 4th true ?

Answer (score 1):

Before we start, there are a few things we could deduce.

First, the complete sequence is a subsequence in itself. So, if the sequence doesn't converge, it exists a subsequence that doesn't converge, 1. is false.

Second, 4. implies 3. If there exits a convergent subsequence, there exist infinitly many convergence subsequences.

**Proof** Let $<a_n>$ be a sequence and $<a_{n_k}>$, a convergent subsequence. If we remove one value from our convergent subsequence, we have a new subsequence that is convergent.

By this, 2. is false.

It remains to prove that 4. is true. It is known as the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. Here is an idea of the proof.

Let $<a_n>$ be a bounded sequence. Then there exist $m, M \in\Bbb R$ such that $a_n\in[m, M]$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$. Let split this interval in two equal parts of length $\frac{M-n}2$. Then one of those parts has an infinite number of point. Let's take $a_{n_1}$ in that interval.

We split this new interval in two equal parts of length $\frac{M-m}{2^2}$. One of these interval as an infinite number of points in it. Let's take $a_{n_2}$,  with $n_1<n_2$, in that interval.

We continue like that to create a subsequence $<a_{n_k}>$ that converge.

Conclusion 3. and 4. are true.

Comment: A  definition of a sequence on $\Bbb N$ is any function $A$ with domain $\Bbb N,$ although we usually write the sequence as $(A_n)_n$ instead of $(A(n))_n.$ And a sub-sequence can be defined in 2 different ways: (i). The restriction of the domain of $A$ to an infinite subset of $\Bbb N,$ or (ii) a sequence $(A'(n))_n=(A(f(n))_n$ for some strictly increasing $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N.$ Suppose $A(n)=1$ for every $n.$ Then according to (i) there are infinitely many subsequences, but according to (ii), $A'=A.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'm not sure I understand your comment properly or how it applies to my answer. What part of the answer is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Not every sub-sequence of $0,1,2,0,1,2,\cdots$ is convergent,  Although there are clearly more than one  convergent sub-sequence.

You can use this example to discard $1,2$

But, it doesn't let you eliminate 3 or 4.  And you cannot prove anything "by example."

Bolzano-Weistrass will help you out.

And, are not sub-sequences of a convergent sequence convergent?